# Merge or join two datasets using between two numbers in python

Tags: python, pandas, merge

I have got two data sets;

Trying to merge df2 (content data) on df1 (viewed data). Have to use merge. However, the key is not standard but should be a between key.

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({"ID": [1, 2],"start":[7200, 1000],"end":[7400, 1100],"duration":[200, 100]})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({"Prog_start":[7100,7300,980,1050],"Prog_end":[7300,7400,1050,1150],"Prog":["Prog_1","Prog_2","Prog_3","Prog_4"]})

desired_output=pd.DataFrame({"ID":[1,1,2,2],"start":[7200,7200,1000,1000],"end":[7400,7400,1100,1100],"duration":[200,200,100,100],"Prog_start":[7100,7300,980,1050],"Prog_end":[7300,7400,1050,1150],"Prog":["Prog_1","Prog_2","Prog_3","Prog_4"],"Dur_Prog":[100,100,20,50]})
```

[image]

I have tried using iloc and between functions which are not working.

Comment: Can you please explain the logic behind merging?

Comment: I got viewership data of switch on of program and switch off of program. Those are start time and end time of program. In another data set, I got what programs were played in the time that individuals have viewed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can take cartesian product of `df1` and `df2`, then filter only the overlapping intervals, and calculate durations:

```
# cartesian product and interval filtering
z = (df1
         .assign(k=1).merge(df2.assign(k=1), on='k')
         .query('(Prog_start < end) & (Prog_end > start)')
         .drop(columns='k'))

# duration calculation
z['Duration_Prog'] = (np.clip(z['Prog_end'], z['start'], z['end']) -
                      np.clip(z['Prog_start'], z['start'], z['end']))

z
```

Output:

```
   ID  start   end  duration  Prog_start  Prog_end    Prog  Duration_Prog
0   1   7200  7400       200        7100      7300  Prog_1            100
1   1   7200  7400       200        7300      7400  Prog_2            100
6   2   1000  1100       100         980      1050  Prog_3             50
7   2   1000  1100       100        1050      1150  Prog_4             50
```

P.S. Is there a mistake in row 3 of your `desired_output`? It should be `Duration_Prog = 50` if I understand the logic correctly (the overlap is `1000 - 1050`)

P.P.S. And with the newer `pandas` (1.2.0+) you can use `merge` with `how='cross'` to do cartesian join, no need for the temporary `k` column

Comment: You are Right. There was an error. It is supposed to be 50 in Row. The logic you mentioned looks perfect. However, I am getting an error, "You are trying to merge on int64 and object columns. If you wish to proceed you should use pd.concat". I looked at the Dtypes. Both the columns in both the datasets are int64

Comment: You probably have some other columns in `df1` and `df2` that overlap then. Try setting the `on='k'` in the `merge`: `.assign(k=1).merge(df2.assign(k=1), on='k')`

Comment: Updated that in my answer

Comment: Yes. It worked now. Thank you. It worked like a charm. I will try and work out on the how='cross' join.

Comment: Excellent! Re `how='cross'`, you can just do `df1.merge(df2, how='cross')` and you don't need to `drop(columns='k')` later, so it's more concise, but it only works with `pandas` version 1.2.0+